# Image is not displaying Django + Angular

Tags: angularjs, django, django-rest-framework

Earlier I was facing problem when I refresh the page. With this [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31647175/3898339) I manage to solve the problem. But after applying this to url pattern, image is not loading properly. If I try to open the source of image in new tab , it redirects me to index page.

When url pattern is  `url(r'^.*$', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),` image is not displayed but page is refreshed properly .

When url pattern is  `url(r'^$', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),` image is displayed but page is not refreshed properly (Page not found) error

How to solve this.

Update:
urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^api/v1/', include(router.urls)),
url(r'^api/v1/auth/login/$', LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
url(r'^api/v1/auth/logout/$', LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
url(r'^api/v1/', include(accounts_router.urls)),
url(r'^api/v1/', include(profiles_router.urls)),
url(r'^blogs/',include('blogs.urls')),
url(r'^account_data/',include('customauth.urls')),
url(r'^.*$', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
#url(r'^customauth/',include('customauth.urls')),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns+=static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns+=static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: seems like it is the problem with media path & the regular expression,post your `urls.py` for checking details

Comment: Update urls.py added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In django urls are resolved from list's 0th index, so `.*` has higher priority than `/static/` or `/media/`, so change the order of urls to get `static` & `media` urls higher priority than `IndexView`.

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^api/v1/', include(router.urls)),
url(r'^api/v1/auth/login/$', LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
url(r'^api/v1/auth/logout/$', LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
url(r'^api/v1/', include(accounts_router.urls)),
url(r'^api/v1/', include(profiles_router.urls)),
url(r'^blogs/',include('blogs.urls')),
url(r'^account_data/',include('customauth.urls')),
#url(r'^customauth/',include('customauth.urls')), rest of the urls
]
if settings.DEBUG:          
    # static & media urls
    pass  
urlpatterns+= [url(r'^.*$', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),] # accepts any urls otherthan above
```